# Is it possible to get the physical setup of the cluster from spark job ?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am aware of

```
spark.sparkContext.statusTracker
```

but I can only have access to the number of `Executors` and the number of active `Tasks`.

I am wondering if it is possible to get information about the physical machines ? Like the number of CPU, memory, etc... I am hosting a cluster on EC2 and I would like to be able to keep track in my main log of the cluster configuration something like:

```
 6 r3.2xlarge 16 CPU 12 GB
 12 r3.xlarge 8 CPU 12GB RAM
```

^ The number are bs here but it is to give an idea of the type of information I'd like to print out.

Thank you.

Comment: I am skeptical of being able to get this information from spark. But since you're on AWS, perhaps you could get it from there? Depends a lot on how you have set up your cluster, but you can probably get this data from "describe instances" API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-ec2-instances.html

Comment: yeah that was my plan B to pass the ID of the cluster to the job and let it fetch but if it was already included within spark that would have been easier :D